# Python Celery Save Results in Database Asynchronously

Tags: python, database, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Python with Celery and RabbitMQ to make a web spider to count the number of links on a page.

Can a database, such as MySQL, be written into asynchronously?  Is it OK to commit the changes after every row added, or is it required to batch them (multi-add) and then commit after a certain number of rows/duration?

I'd prefer to use SQLAlchemy and MySQL, unless there is a more recommended combination for Celery/RabbitMQ.  I also see NoSQL (CouchDB?) recommended.

Comment: You could commit the changes each N inserts, with N decently high. http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/improve_mysql_insert_performance/

Comment: How would I deal with database locking when writing asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For write intensive operation like Counters and Logs NoSQL solution are always the best choice. Personally I use a mongoDB for this kind of tasks.